# Access Control Lists -- wrong permission?

Tags: permissions, acl

Created file1 and gave 000 permission.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ltr file1
----------. 1 root root 0 Jan 28 08:09 file1
```

Gave "test" user rw permission using access control lists:

```
setfacl -m u:test:rw file1
```

file1 permission for selinux is correct

```
[root@localhost ~]# getfacl file1
# file: file1
# owner: root
# group: root
user::---
user:test:rw-
group::---
mask::rw-
other::---
```

but when i see file permission it's showing 060

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ltr file1
----rw----+ 1 root root 0 Jan 28 08:09 file1
```

Question : from where this 060 permission coming ?

Comment: there's nothing selinux related in your question -- feel free to re-edit your question but please do not put the selinux bits back in ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For files that have `acl(5)` extended attributes, the 3 group bits from the file mask may have a different meaning -- they're the `ACL_MASK`, ie the maximum access rights that can be granted by the `ACL_USER`, `ACL_GROUP_OBJ` and `ACL_GROUP` permissions stored in the ACL extended attribute. Quoting from the `acl(5)` manpage:

> There is a correspondence between the file owner, group, and other permissions and specific ACL entries: the owner permissions correspond to
>        the permissions of the `ACL_USER_OBJ` entry. If the ACL has an `ACL_MASK`
>        entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the
>        `ACL_MASK` entry.  Otherwise, if the `ACL` has no `ACL_MASK` entry, the group
>        permissions correspond to the permissions of the `ACL_GROUP_OBJ` entry.
>        The other permissions correspond to the permissions of the `ACL_OTHER_OBJ`
>        entry

Since you have given the `test` user `rw` permissions, and did *not* use the `-n` option of `setfacl(1)` ("do not recalculate the effective rights mask"), the ACL mask has been correctly set to `rw`.